# Sort folders by size in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

Is there any way, to sort sub-folders in a folder or a whole volume (such as the root drive where macOS is installed) by size? Is it possible to do without resorting to a 3rd party app?

Answer (score 10):

If you open the folder in finder such that your sub-folders are displayed you can click on size at the top of the list. If the folder sizes are not displayed, open finder and under the View menu select "Show View Options". This brings up a pane like an image shown below.

[image]

At the bottom of the pane is a checkbox to determine folder size. Check the box and folder sizes will be displays. Then by clicking on the size near the top of the Finder window. the contents should be sorted by size.

You need to make sure size is shown in the Finder window. To ensure this is the case, in the pane we just looked at, be sure to check "Size".

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That's quite useful.  However, I'm still not able to sort all items in the whole volume by size (including folders, with should appear on top).  I tried doing an advanced search for all items modified before today, or for all items of kind: folder, which shows all items (including folders) but folders don't show dates, and the checkbox "calculate all sizes" is greyed out.  Your answer was useful anyway!

Comment: This solution works only in List mode, not Columns. Otherwise, the options isn't even present

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get an estimate of storage, and not always use the sorted mode, you can use About this Mac.app.

Open it, storage tab, manage, Documents tab, File Browser. This will take some time and CPU but it will sort everything eventually.

Comment: That's a great way to sort stuff in the home folder, thanks a lot.